# How to count specific elements and limit number of them with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, count, limit

For example:

> string/text field = "United, Arsenal, Chelsea"

I need to allow *only 3 clubs* entered in text field separated by `","`, if user try to enter fourth club it needs to ignore it and allow only removing of existing clubs and writing new instead of some existing.

I've done it but when i try to enter fourth club it comes to `return false or preventDefault` and stops there, i can't do anything (remove existing club or any of them)...

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {

  $("#sportsText").on("input", function(e) {
  var str = $(this).val();
   
   var comma_count = (str.match(/,/g) || []).length;
   
   if(comma_count > 2)
   {
    $(this).val(str.substring(0, str.length - 1));
   }
 })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">
  <input id="sportsText" type="text">
</div>
```

Also view it on - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwq9bt67/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you...!!